# Kendo file upload: Retrieving details of uploaded file..?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

How to retrieve the details of the uploaded file using sync mode..

```
<form method="post" id="form" action="file.htm">
    <label for="control">Control: <input id="control" type="checkbox"/></label>
    <input name="photos" id="photos" type="file"/>
    <input id="send" class="k-button" type="button" value="Save"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#photos").kendoUpload({
        multiple: false
    });

    $("#send").on("click", function (e) {
        debugger;
        // Check that Checkbox is ticked
        var ctl = $("#control").is(":checked");
        if (ctl) {
            // if so, send the form
            $("#form").submit();
        } else {
            // otherwise show an alert
            alert("Please check 'control' before sending");
        }
    });
</script>
```

here i want to access the details of uploaded file in "e"?